# How do i set a timeout for utils::download.file() in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to download a file that requires more than 60 seconds using download.file() function. The documentation mentions the timeout option e.g.

> The timeout for many parts of the transfer can be set by the option timeout which defaults to 60 seconds.

When i try to set it i get an error message

```
download.file("https://server/FileURL", destfile = "file.xml", timeout = 444)
```

Example Message

```
unused argument (timeout = 444)
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To retrieve an option

```
getOption('timeout')
# [1] 60
```

To set an option

```
options(timeout=100)
```

Comment: Great answer ... if you're sitting in the train with poor WiFi, and have forgotten to install all the necessary R packages in advance :D