# Using R read.csv returning timeout error, despite there being no options to adjust this

Tags: r, read.csv

A few weeks ago this file from this location https://opendata.bristol.gov.uk/explore/dataset/fact-journey-hourly/export/?disjunctive.journeylinkdescription was downloading fine using read.csv() in R.

```
dat -> read.csv("https://opendata.bristol.gov.uk/explore/dataset/fact-journey-hourly/download/?format=csv&timezone=Europe/London&lang=en&use_labels_for_header=true&csv_separator=%3B", sep = ";")
```

error: ': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached' error.

It downloads fine manually although is quite slow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282928/how-do-i-set-a-timeout-for-utilsdownload-file-in-r

Comment: This is not answering the question - what about read.csv? This worked fine until a few weeks ago - what has changed?!

Comment: Even if there were no code/R-environment changes, downloading is _asynchronous_.  Could be any of many things most not R-related at the client end. Could be server/net changes and/or status issues as well. Especially if the download proceeds "fine", it really isn't an issue, Or are you doing real time analysis?

Comment: Added: It's possible that read_csv() from the tidyverse readr package has updated code that will work better. http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/12/reading-csv-files-in-r-readcsv-vs.html  Also read_csv avoidss the dreaded "strings as factors" problem.